# What are all the different places a redirect may be set on a Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2012, redirect

I'm currently trying to find where a particular redirect is set and can't find the source! It's on a Windows Server 2012 (load balanced).

Places I have checked:

1. The HTTP redirect in IIS 8 for the file affected and its folder (on both load balanced servers)
2. The web.config for the folder the file resides in and the global web.config
3. The DNS server
4. Back end (c#) and front end code (js)
5. A database table where we hold a handful of redirects (don't ask, this is an old running website with several devs along the years)

Is there a particular obvious place that I should be looking at for this mysterious redirect?

---

**Edit:** 
Plot twist! Using IIS, we were able to set a redirect on the troubled page. This works on all browsers and machines, except Firefox of my machine only! It works on Chrome and IE on my computer but not firefox! It works fine in all browsers of my colleagues computers, under the same office/network. Gob smacked!

So all along I was chasing an error that only I can see in Firefox! What's going on?!

Comment: How about on the load balancer?

Comment: That's the domain of the hosting provider, we don't have access to it. So this would have never been changed by our devs.

Comment: So all along I was chasing an error that only I can see in Firefox! What's going on?! : you probably had a redirect permanent response, that prevents browsers resending the GET to the original address, the only way to get firefox to 'retry' is by restarting it.